# Where is pyCSW metadata repository stored in GeoNode?

Tags: metadata, geonode, pycsw

I have a working instance of GeoNode 2.0 over Debian7 (with PostgreSQL) and I want to know where does pyCSW stores the metadata by default. And if it's possible, how to set it to the same PSQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoNode comes with [pycsw](http://pycsw.org) as the built-in CSW instance, so on any GeoNode instance you can connect to the CSW endpoint via `http://host/catalogue/csw`.

pycsw's GeoNode [support](http://docs.pycsw.org/en/latest/geonode.html) works off the same underlying database as GeoNode itself via mappings, so there is no duplication.  pycsw uses GeoNode Django/etc. models [directly](https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/pycsw/plugins/repository/geonode/geonode_.py), and GeoNode's defined model [mappings](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/catalogue/backends/pycsw_local_mappings.py) to enable seamless/direct access.

Having said this, if you would like to connect pycsw to a GeoNode metadata repository, try the following in the pycsw configuration

```
[repository]
database=postgresql://username:password@localhost/database_name # i.e. actual connection to the GeoNode DB
mappings=path/to/mappings.py # identical to https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/catalogue/backends/pycsw_local_mappings.py
table=base_resourcebase # the internal tablename created by Django
```

Comment: Thanks Tom!!
I found that metadata is stored at "base_*" tables. Now I need to know how to import metadata from GeoNetwork.
Is there any tutorial??

Comment: There are some notes at http://docs.pycsw.org/en/latest/transactions.html and http://geopython.github.io/pycsw-workshop/docs/advanced/harvesting.html.  You can invoke a `Harvest` operation against the GeoNetwork CSW.  Sample request: https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/tests/suites/harvesting/post/Harvest-csw-run1.xml